# Is my logic to check data in database efficient?

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I use laravel 5.6

I have a json file containing 500 thousand records. I want to create a logic to check whether the id of each record already exists or not in the database. If it doesn't already exist, then there will be a data insert process. If it already exists, there will be a data update process. Before updating the data, it will check whether last_modified_date in json file and database is the same or different. If it's different then it will update

I have made logic. I just want to make sure whether my logic is effective or not

My logic code like this :

```
$path = storage_path('data.json');
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($path), true);
foreach ($json['value'] as $value) {
    $last_modified_date = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($value['Last_Modified_Date']);
    $data = \DB::table('details')->where('id', '=', $value['Code'])->get();
    if ($data->isEmpty()) {
        \DB::table('details')->insert(
            [
                'id' => $value['Code'],
                'number' => $value['Number'],
                'last_modified_at' => $last_modified_date,
                ...
            ]
        );
    }
    else {
        \DB::table('details')
            ->where('id', '=', $value['Code'])
            ->where('last_modified_at', '<>', $last_modified_date)
            ->update([
                'id' => $value['Code'],
                'number' => $value['Number'],
                'last_modified_at' => $last_modified_date,
                ...
            ]);
    }
}
```

The code is working. But the process seems really long

Do you have another solution that is better?

**Update**

I find another solution use `updateOrCreate`

I try like this :

```
$path = storage_path('data.json');
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($path), true);
foreach ($json['value'] as $value) {
    Details::updateOrCreate(
        [ 'id' => $value['Code'] ],
        [ 'number' => $value['Number'], 'last_modified_at' => $last_modified_date, ... ]
    );
}
```

What do you think?

Comment: @lagbox Yes, this is the same. But I have another case where before updating check last_modified_date first. If the last_modified_data between database and json is different, then it will update the data. I want to make sure that using `UpdateOrCreate` is correct.

Comment: sometime it's better change your logic to make your code to be more effective.

Comment: @Mohsen Safari So you mean a new case can I use `updateOrCreate`? This case is a bit different from the previous case. It will check whether last_modified_date in json file and database is the same or different. If it's different then it will update. I want to make sure whether this case can use `updateOrCreate` or not. I hope you give a definite answer

Comment: no you can not use `<>` in `updateOrCreate` condition

Comment: @Mohsen Safari So what's the best solution for my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not use `<>` in `updateOrCreate`

i hope this code could help you:

```
$path = storage_path('data.json');
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($path), true);
foreach ($json['value'] as $value) {
    $detail = Details::firstOrCreate(
        [ 'id' => $value['Code'] ],
        [ 'number' => $value['Number'], 'last_modified_at' => $last_modified_date, ... ]
    );
    if($detail->last_modified_at != $last_modified_date) {
        $detail->update([
            'number' => $value['Number'],
            'last_modified_at' => $last_modified_date,
            ...
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay. I want to ask. Why do you prefer to use  `if($detail->last_modified_at != $last_modified_date) { `than `->where('last_modified_at', '<>', $last_modified_date)`?

Comment: @SuccessMan your condition run a query then if condition was true then update record, but in my case there is no need to run query for check condition

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot

Comment: Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52147336/how-can-i-solve-fatal-error-out-of-memory-when-i-run-command-schedule-lara